# WebGL - Rendering multiple copies of a single object in different locations in shaders

Tags: webgl, shader

I'm attempting to write a pair of vertex/fragment shaders in webGL to be able to read the location and orientation of a single object and render multiple instances of that one object in those locations.

From my understanding the vertex and fragment shaders each set a variable i.e. gl_Position and gl_FragColor to define the position and pixel color of any given input. So how would I go about rendering multiple instances? Should I simply set the value for gl_Position and gl_FragColor multiple times through a loop for all the copies I want rendered?

This is for an assignment so I'd like for some explanation as to how I should tackle this problem theoretically.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: The short answer is you use uniforms to modify the output of your shaders by setting them to different values before each draw call. It sounds like you'd be better served by reading some tutorials on WebGL. [Here's some](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over the instances of your object. For each instance, set uniforms specifying the position offset and the color of the current instance and then issue a draw call to render the corresponding instance. The vertex shader should use the passed position offset to compute the actual position of the instance in world coordinates, transform it using the model view projection matrix and write the result in `gl_Position`. In the fragment shader, the passed color should be used to derive the final fragment color written in `gl_FragColor`.

If the number of object instances is very large (to the point that too many draw calls need to be issued), then pack all the relevant data for your instances into one (or multiple) large vertex buffers and issue a single draw call for all the instances stored in this(ese) vertex buffer(s).

Finally note that WebGL does not currently support instancing in the core API but there is one extension that provides this functionality: [ANGLE_instanced_arrays](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/ANGLE_instanced_arrays/).

Comment: Thank you very much, it took a while to comprehend exactly how to do this but I got it in the end.

Comment: +1. If all relevant data is packed into a large vertex buffer, how does the vertex shader know how to process each instance? Does it have anything to do with the stride information?

Comment: The stride has more to do with multiple interleaved vertex attributes. The large vertex buffer(s) should contain all the information needed to render the instances. This can include color, position, etc... (which have to be specified for each instance). With the ANGLE_instanced_arrays extension, the rate at which each vertex attribute is consumed can be set independently: one can thus avoid specifying repeatedly the same value for an instance attribute (but use the same color for every N instances for example).

Answer (score 0):

The questions sounds like you're asking if there's a way to multiply a primitive within your shader program, where you only need to feed three vertices of a triangle into the pipeline and your hardware would draw several of them at different positions.

The answer is: you'd need a geometry shader for this. Unfortunately geometry shaders aren't part of the current WebGL specification. So the only way to do this is to loop through your buffer object while changing shader uniforms between each draw.